# Is the only way to list the "live" revisions of a particular SVN path "svn log -q -v" plus a filter?

Tags: svn, path, revision

Is performing an "svn log -q -v" across all revisions against the repository root and then filtering by the desired path really the best (only?) way to do this?  We need to find these ranges in order to provide peg revisions to an automated tool and to add supporting detail to our change reporting.

<strike>I have made a slight optimization to querying the root already:</strike>

Given a path:

protocol://server/repo/a/b/c/d/foo.txt

I've already written a script to perform repeated svn log queries up the path:

svn log -q -v .../a/b/c/d/foo.txt
svn log -q -v .../a/b/c/d
svn log -q -v .../a/b/c
svn log -q -v .../a/b
svn log -q -v .../a
svn log -q -v ...

until I don't get:

svn: File not found: ...

I have not run significant profiling tests, but it seems to me that the errors should be processed rather rapidly and the overall potential reduction in network traffic should outweigh the cost of the repeated queries in all cases except the one in which the repository root must be queried anyway.

The above doesn't work if the ancestor has multiple live ranges; unless someone knows better, my only option is to query from the repository root.

From the results, I essentially want the list of distinct ranges where the file exists (which I may later amend to also track history, such that a resurrected file has multiple ranges; as perverse as it may sound, we do have cases where files with the same path end up being unrelated).  At the moment, I am parsing revision numbers as they pass, keeping track of the last revision of the desired path where it or one of its ancestors was deleted (initially HEAD, which will be overwritten if I see a delete).  When I see that the path has been added, I dump out a range `rev_added - rev_lastdeleted`.

The above works, but it does involve traipsing through quite a bit of information, most of it spurious.  Is there a more efficient way to do this, preferably one in which more work is done on the server side in order to minimize network traffic (a lot of our work is done remotely via VPN)?

It seems that the only way TortoiseSVN provides this same information is by performing the same process (get the log of an ancestor and then filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think so.  If you want to format this data in a certain way, then you’ll have to take SVN’s output and process it like you’re doing.

The output from `svn log filename` should give you all the relevant revisions for `filename` — including its history of moves/renames — which you can then format however you want.

Comment: Only for a particular peg revision; if I add foo.txt in rev 100, delete it in rev 110 and then create a brand new, unrelated (as far as history is concerned) foo.txt and add it in rev 115, then svn log foo.txt only shows -r 115:HEAD by default.  I will not see anything from -r 100:110

Comment: To clarify, even specifying -r 0:HEAD to svn log will still only show changes in -r 115:HEAD.  In the example I just gave, even if I specify a peg revision (foo.txt@100) it still doesn't show the delete in rev 110, and svn log foo.txt@110 complains that the file doesn't exist in rev 110.  So, the only way I can see to see ALL of the history associated with the path is to get the log for the directory.  Of course, if the directory also has disjoint history segments, you have to move up to ITS directory, potentially until one reaches the root. *sigh*

Comment: So then I think my answer of “no” is correct.  In the future, you can prevent gaps in the history by restoring a deleted file from an old revision rather than creating a new one at the same path.  In this way, SVN’s history will track it in the way you want.  Only if the files are truly unrelated should you create a new one, and in this case you wouldn’t want the history to track the old file.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer of "no" is incorrect.  In several cases, I actually do want the files to be unrelated, e.g. the old file was later refactored to a few other files, and, since it wasn't well named to begin with, we created a new file with the same name that actually serves the purpose of the original.  However, for reporting, we still need to know available peg revisions for a given path.  I still don't see a mechanism that is correct for all possible situations besides a walk of the entire path status history for the entire repository.

Comment: Either way, I guess the answer is "no"; there isn't a better way to do this; maybe I'll look into extending the svn protocol to support this, and to get something closer to a changeset than is possible using the ugly combination of log, diff, and ls.